# How to batch generate EDL (edit decision list) files for a folder of videos with different run times

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mplayer, kodi

How can I skip an exact amount of seconds from the start, and another amount of seconds from the end, for a collection of videos whose durations differ?

This is the format for the EDL I am using with kodi

```
0:00:00   0:01:20.    3
```

So if the video is 40 mins 30 seconds the EDL generated skipping 80 seconds from the start and 90 seconds from the end should be

```
0:00:00   0:01:20.    3
0:39:00   0:40:30.    3
```

More info about [kodi EDL](https://kodi.wiki/view/Edit_decision_list).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Skip intro and outro?

Comment: Yeah more or less.

Comment: Are you aware of Notrobro? https://github.com/xbmc/notrobro Which is still quiet experimental, but might help you?

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of this and although it works it takes a lot of processor power to run through all the files to detect intro and outros. Which is waste if you already know how many seconds you need to skip.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ffprobe` or any other media too to get duration then subtract ending interval. Example:

```
bc <<< $(ffprobe -i "mediafile.mkv" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")-90
```

mplayer EDL support time tags in seconds.